# Numpy SVD gives infinite singular values for array with finite elements

Tags: python, numpy, svd, infinity

I've run into this problem (infinite singular values despite finite entries in an array) several times for relatively small arrays with dimensions around 100 by 100. The arrays are large enough that I've struggled to see a pattern. I give a working example below that I found by rounding the values in one of my matrices, though I wish I could engineer a simpler example.

```
import numpy as np
kmat = np.zeros((81, 81), dtype='complex')

kmat[([30, 32, 36, 36, 38, 38, 57, 57, 59, 59, 63, 65], [68, 14, 62, 74, 8, 20, 61, 73, 7, 19, 67, 13])] = (0.04+0.03j)
kmat[([31, 31, 37, 58, 64, 64],[35, 47, 41, 40, 34, 46])] = (0.16+0.11j)
kmat[([33, 33, 35, 35, 39, 41, 45, 45, 47, 47, 60, 62, 66, 66, 68, 68, 72, 74], [62, 74,  8, 20, 68, 14, 62, 74,  8, 20, 67, 13, 61, 73,  7, 19, 67, 13])] = (0.03+0.02j)
kmat[([34, 40, 40, 46, 61, 61, 67, 73, 73], [41, 35, 47, 41, 34, 46, 40, 34, 46])] = (0.13+0.09j)

kmat[([30, 30, 32, 32, 36, 38, 57, 59, 63, 63, 65, 65], [62, 74,  8, 20, 68, 14, 67, 13, 61, 73,  7, 19])] = -(0.04+0.03j)
kmat[([31, 37, 37, 58, 58, 64], [41, 35, 47, 34, 46, 40])] = -(0.16+0.11j)
kmat[([33, 35, 39, 39, 41, 41, 45, 47, 60, 60, 62, 62, 66, 68, 72, 72, 74, 74], [68, 14, 62, 74,  8, 20, 68, 14, 61, 73,  7, 19, 67, 13, 61, 73,  7, 19])] = -(0.03+0.02j)
kmat[([34, 34, 40, 46, 46, 61, 67, 67, 73], [35, 47, 41, 35, 47, 40, 34, 46, 40])] = -(0.13+0.09j)

print(np.linalg.svd(kmat, full_matrices = 0, compute_uv = 0))
```

The output is

```
[            inf 6.71714225e-001 6.71714225e-001 1.63401346e-001
 1.63401346e-001 1.63401346e-001 5.06904064e-017 4.89771960e-017
 2.03140157e-017 1.72656309e-017 1.40275705e-017 3.53543469e-018
 1.83729709e-018 1.12027584e-018 8.52297427e-020 1.81345172e-033
 1.27726594e-034 8.75935866e-035 2.02878907e-036 9.30164632e-049
 8.54881928e-050 6.95546444e-051 2.49250115e-052 4.92974326e-053
 1.18027016e-064 2.83787877e-066 3.61447306e-067 2.40364993e-069
 2.01469630e-069 6.85315161e-081 1.15983261e-085 9.21712550e-086
 3.87403183e-097 6.63966512e-102 5.67626333e-102 4.16050009e-118
 3.27338859e-134 2.33809507e-150 1.55632960e-166 1.82909508e-182
 1.14892283e-198 1.51906443e-214             nan             nan
             nan             nan             nan             nan
             nan             nan             nan             nan
             nan             nan             nan 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000             nan             nan
             nan 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000
 0.00000000e+000]
```

The largest singular value is returned as infinity, `inf`. There are also 18 `nan` returned, as well as well as some nonzero and zero singular values. However, since every element of my array is not infinite, I don't see where this trouble is originating from.

---

Why is numpy's `svd` giving an infinite singular value for an array with finite values and what can I do to avoid this?

---

In searching for the answer, I've tried a variety of 3 by 3 matrices, such as those with a column or row of zeros, but the singular values appear to be fine.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Not only all entries printed are finite but all of them smaller then `10` with many of them practically `0`, e.g. `6.40817840e-051`. Can you add the error message or show your output?

Comment: @7shoe Thank you, that might be a big clue. I've edited my question and added the output I see. I'm running a fresh version of Google Colab; my output can also be seen here https://imgur.com/a/CZHITTZ. The version of numpy that I'm running is 1.21.6.

Comment: @7shoe Quick update, I've also just reproduced the error on a machine running 1.18.1

Comment: Thank you, I still get `any(np.isnan(np.linalg.svd(kmat, full_matrices = 0, compute_uv = 0))) >False` indicating no `nan` entry. I am running version 1.19.2 though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on Intel processors. You can fix this by installing the intel-numpy package.

```
pip install intel-numpy
```

More information: https://anaconda.org/intel/numpy